# Set an image from Firebase as the background of div via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get an image from fire base and set it as the background of a div. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried all of my ideas and they did not work. Can someone provide any examples?

```
<div class="museBGSize rounded-corners grpelem" id="u525"></div>
```

I tried it this way and it didn't work:

```
fbRef4.on("child_added", snap => {
    var image = snap.child("Image").val();
    //concatenated the img tag using the image variable at the top
    $("#tableBody3").append("<img src=" + image + "/img>");
});
```

Comment: Well for one thing, `"<img src=" + image + "/img>"` should be written as `"<img src='" + image + "' />"`. Additionally we might need some more code to fully understand your problem. For example, it might be helpful to see what `#tableBody3` refers to.

Comment: `it didn't work` - you'll need to expand on this? Were there errors in the developer tools console? errors in the developer tools network tab? Did  it cause your dog to run away or your house to burn down?

Comment: ok just imagine tablebody3 is a an id of a div

Comment: i post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello every one i found an answer for it and will post the answer just in case if some one want to know 
((my html))

```
<div class="museBGSize rounded-corners grpelem" id="u525"><!-- simple frame --></div>
```

((my js))

```
var fbRef4 = firebase.database().ref().child("slide"); 
fbRef4.on("child_added", snap => {

    var image = snap.child("Image").val();
var newimgsrc = 'image' + (new Date().getTime());
  var newimg = $('#u525'); 

    $('#u525').css("background-image", "url("+image+")");
    newimg.css({'background-image': 'url('+image+')'});
    newimg.show();
});
```

((my firebase))

```
-slide
 -asdasdasd
    Image:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/awe..."
```

Comment: Good practice to share you own investigation. +1